# Class SimpleContextFactory not found when running Pentaho PDI job using Java API

Tags: pentaho, kettle, pentaho-data-integration

I'm runnning a Pentaho PDI/Kettle job in a Play for Scala application server. I added `kettle-core-7.0.0-12.jar` and `kettle-engine-7.0.0-12.jar` to the classpath and it works fine the first time, but the **second** time it throws an error:

> ClassNotFoundException: org.osjava.sj.SimpleContextFactory

The first question is why the class *is* found (or not used) the first time? After some research, I found that the jar `simple-jndi` needs to be added to the classpath along with a `simple-jndi` directory that contains a `jdbc.properties` file. But after doing so, *none* of my application JNDI connections work, I get:

> Error injecting constructor,
>   org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested
>   service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]

There seems to be a conflict between Pentaho's and Play's JNDI connections. Not clear why Pentaho needs the `simple-jndi` jar as the first time it's not using it and it runs fine. I don't want Pentaho to use JNDI to connect to the repository, just plain JDBC.

This is how I run the job, any ideas will be welcome.

```
    KettleEnvironment.init
    val databaseMeta = new DatabaseMeta("ETL", dbType, "JDBC", host, 
                                    db, port, dbUserName, dbPassword)
    val repository = new KettleDatabaseRepository
    val repositoryMeta = new KettleDatabaseRepositoryMeta
    repositoryMeta.setConnection(databaseMeta)
    repository.init(repositoryMeta)
    val conn = repository.connect(repUserName, repPassword)

    // load the job
    val dir = repository.findDirectory("/some dir")
    val jobMeta = repository.loadJob("General ETL", dir, null, null)
    val job = new Job(repository, jobMeta)

    // run the ETL job
    jobMeta.setParameterValue("INPUT_DATE", dateStr)
    job.start
    job.waitUntilFinished
    val result = job.getResult
```

**UPDATE**

I added the following line to force the connection to native JDBC, but get the same error:

```
databaseMeta.setAccessType(DatabaseMeta.TYPE_ACCESS_NATIVE)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer [here](https://forums.pentaho.com/threads/129240-Transformation-cannot-use-JNDI-Datasource-from-Tomcat/)

Call `KettleEnvironment.init(false)` where `false` means don't use JNDI